# Is possible to give a mathematical expression as argument in C language?

Tags: c, math, mathematical-expressions

I'm trying to built a function which i can give as argument a mathematical expression such as "x**3+bx-c" and trough the newton method return me the roots of the given function.

I was thinking in something like this following example, where 'r0' is an initial random number non-zero and dfunc is the derivative of the function. I don't know how i'll evaluate the derivative, but i want to know first if is possible what i want to do with the expression as an argument.

```c
double * roots (double r0, <type> func) {
   double *r = alloc(100, sizeof(double));
   r[0] = r0;

   for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      r[i]=r[i-1]-func(r[i-1])/dfunc(r[i-1]);
   };

   return r;
};
```

Comment: You can use a function pointer.

Comment: Then you define a function that calculates the expression, and pass the function as an argument to `roots()`.

Comment: Are the functions always polynomials? If so then you can represent a function with a vector of coefficients, and constructing the derivative is easy.

Comment: @Beta yes, always polynomials of degree 3 or above.

Comment: Note: `r[i]= ...` is a problem when `i==100`.  I suspect you want `for (int i = 1; i < /* = */ 100; i++) {`

Comment: Marino, Please post a sample polynomial function of yours.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Looks like there is one already in the question. "x**3+bx-c"

Comment: @Yunnosch That is a math function,  So maybe more explicit: Marino, Please post a sample of C code that does the polynomial function of yours.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica something like what i already wrote, now i was going to try with `double function(double x) {return x*(x*x-x-1); }`

Answer (score 2):

Others have suggested using function pointes, and I agree that this is probably the correct solution, but you did ask for a way to provide expressions to a function. You can do this, of course, but you have to implement expressions yourself.

You can make a structure for the various kinds of sub-expressions you want, and it could look like this:

```c
struct expr
{
    int refcount; // GC; exprs share sub-expressions
    enum
    {
        CONS, VAR, MINUS, /* unary minus */
        ADD, SUB, /* binary subtraction */
        MUL, /* more... */
    } type;
    union {
        struct { double x;                          } cons;
        struct { int idx; /* index in var vector */ } var;
        struct { struct expr *x;                    } unary;
        struct { struct expr *x, *y;                } binary;
    };
};
```

I've just stuck to some easy ones here.

In the derivative code below, I need to keep expressions in the multiplication rule (and you would need to do the same with the chain rule if you implement that), so I handle memory management with reference counters.

```c
struct expr *incref(struct expr *expr)
{
    expr->refcount++;
    return expr;
}

void free_expr(struct expr *);
struct expr *decref(struct expr *expr)
{
    expr->refcount--;
    if (expr->refcount > 1)
        return expr;
    free_expr(expr);
    return 0;
}
```

I return a pointer to the object I modify because I will need that for `incref`. I don't use it for `decref`, but I preferred to keep the interface for the two functions consistent.

There is nothing much to creating instances of expressions; you just allocate and set the values in them.

```c
struct expr *new_const(double x)
{
    struct expr *expr = malloc(sizeof *expr);
    assert(expr); // handle alloc errors
    *expr = (struct expr){.refcount = 1, .type = CONS, .cons = {x}};
    return expr;
}

struct expr *new_var(int idx)
{
    struct expr *expr = malloc(sizeof *expr);
    assert(expr); // handle alloc errors
    *expr = (struct expr){.refcount = 1, .type = VAR, .var = {idx}};
    return expr;
}

struct expr *new_minus(struct expr *x)
{
    struct expr *expr = malloc(sizeof *expr);
    assert(expr); // handle alloc errors
    *expr = (struct expr){.refcount = 1, .type = MINUS, .unary = {x}};
    return expr;
}

struct expr *new_add(struct expr *x, struct expr *y)
{
    struct expr *expr = malloc(sizeof *expr);
    assert(expr); // handle alloc errors
    *expr = (struct expr){.refcount = 1, .type = ADD, .binary = {x, y}};
    return expr;
}

struct expr *new_sub(struct expr *x, struct expr *y)
{
    struct expr *expr = malloc(sizeof *expr);
    assert(expr); // handle alloc errors
    *expr = (struct expr){.refcount = 1, .type = SUB, .binary = {x, y}};
    return expr;
}

struct expr *new_mul(struct expr *x, struct expr *y)
{
    struct expr *expr = malloc(sizeof *expr);
    assert(expr); // handle alloc errors
    *expr = (struct expr){.refcount = 1, .type = MUL, .binary = {x, y}};
    return expr;
}
```

For functions that work on them, you can use a `switch`:

```c
void print_expr(struct expr *expr)
{
    switch (expr->type)
    {
    case CONS:
        printf("%f", expr->cons.x);
        break;
    case VAR:
        printf("x%d", expr->var.idx);
        break;
    case MINUS:
        printf("-(");
        print_expr(expr->unary.x);
        printf(")");
        break;
    case ADD:
        printf("(");
        print_expr(expr->binary.x);
        printf(" + ");
        print_expr(expr->binary.y);
        printf(")");
        break;
    case SUB:
        printf("(");
        print_expr(expr->binary.x);
        printf(" - ");
        print_expr(expr->binary.y);
        printf(")");
        break;
    case MUL:
        printf("(");
        print_expr(expr->binary.x);
        printf(" * ");
        print_expr(expr->binary.y);
        printf(")");
        break;

        /* more here ... */
    }
}
```

With function pointers you can implement polymorphism to avoid the switching, but that is probably overkill here.

If you want to evaluate an expression, you need to provide values for the variables, and an easy solution is to just use an array. That is why the variables above contain an index rather than a string or similar. The index is interpreted as the offset into the array of variable values.

```c
double eval_expr(struct expr *expr, double *x)
{
    switch (expr->type)
    {
    case CONS:
        return expr->cons.x;
    case VAR:
        return x[expr->var.idx];
    case MINUS:
        return -eval_expr(expr->unary.x, x);
    case ADD:
        return eval_expr(expr->binary.x, x) + eval_expr(expr->binary.y, x);
    case SUB:
        return eval_expr(expr->binary.x, x) - eval_expr(expr->binary.y, x);
    case MUL:
        return eval_expr(expr->binary.x, x) * eval_expr(expr->binary.y, x);

        /* more here ... */
    }
}
```

To calculate the derivative, you implement transformation rules according to the derivation rules (which is why I kept to simple expressions here; I didn't want to write code for the chain rule or division and such; I am a very lazy man).

```c
struct expr *derivative(struct expr *expr, int var)
{
    switch (expr->type)
    {
    case CONS:
        return new_const(0);
    case VAR:
        return (expr->var.idx == var) ? new_const(1) : new_const(0);
    case MINUS:
        return new_minus(derivative(expr->unary.x, var));
    case ADD:
        return new_add(derivative(expr->binary.x, var), derivative(expr->binary.y, var));
    case SUB:
        return new_sub(derivative(expr->binary.x, var), derivative(expr->binary.y, var));
    case MUL:
        return new_add(new_mul(incref(expr->binary.x), derivative(expr->binary.y, var)),
                       new_mul(derivative(expr->binary.x, var), incref(expr->binary.y)));

        /* more here ... */
    }
}
```

I use `incref` in the multiplication rule, so I can reuse the incoming expressions and still free memory safely. Freeing an expression is quite simple then:

```c
void free_expr(struct expr *expr)
{
    switch (expr->type)
    {
    case CONS:
    case VAR:
        break;
    case MINUS:
        decref(expr->unary.x);
        break;
    case ADD:
    case SUB:
    case MUL:
        decref(expr->binary.x);
        decref(expr->binary.y);
        break;

        /* more here ... */
    }
    free(expr);
}
```

You can use these expressions like this:

```c
int main(void)
{
    struct expr *expr =
        new_mul(
            new_add(
                new_const(3.5),
                new_minus(new_var(0))),
            new_sub(new_const(1.4),
                    new_var(1)));

    print_expr(expr);
    putchar('\n');

    double x[] = {2.0, 42.0}; // variables
    printf("value: %f\n", eval_expr(expr, x));

    struct expr *deriv = derivative(expr, 0);
    printf("derivative with respect to x0:\n");
    print_expr(deriv);
    putchar('\n');
    printf("derivative value: %f\n", eval_expr(deriv, x));

    free_expr(deriv);
    deriv = derivative(expr, 1);
    printf("derivative with respect to x1:\n");
    print_expr(deriv);
    putchar('\n');
    printf("derivative value: %f\n", eval_expr(deriv, x));

    free_expr(deriv);
    free_expr(expr);

    return 0;
}
```

There are most likely errors in this code, I just whipped it up quickly, but it should give an idea about how you could work with expressions.

Comment: Wow! Long and complete job!

Comment: It's mostly just boilerplate code, so it isn't that bad.

Comment: man this is pretty far from what i know, thanks for the response, but i need to study it first

Comment: You probably just want a function pointer, but this lets you manipulate expressions as data.

Answer (score 1):

Given OP's function is like [`double function(double x)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69993475/is-possible-to-give-a-mathematical-expression-as-argument-in-c-language?noredirect=1#comment123737263_69993475), pass the address of that function to `roots()`.

Create a derivative routine that calls `func(x)` from 2 nearby values to determine the slope.

OP's `for` loop only iterates to find 1 root.  Additional code needed to find more.

Also no need for to allocate an array of `double` when looking for one root.  Enough to keep track of current `x` and previous `x`.

```
extern func(double func(double), x);

double root(double r0, double func(double x)) {
  double x =r0;

  for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    double better_x = x - func(x)/dfunc(func, x);
    x = better_x; 
  };

  return x;
}

// Usage
double y = root(0.0, function);
```

---

OP's application of [Netwon's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) deserves detection of a zero slope, excessive iterations, better stopping criteria than a simple iteration count, etc.

Further, for a *general* `double function(double x)` (and not just a polynomial one) to find the `N+1` roots, additional code needed.

IMO, OP show instead focus on polynomial roots only and create a function of the form:

```
complex double *polynomial_roots(size_t n, const double coefficients[n+1]);
```

See [Bairstow's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairstow%27s_method).

IAC, OP's goal multi-root goal is non-trivial.

Comment: i'm looking in the Bairstow's method, i think it more suitable for what i want to do. Thanks!

Comment: @Marino  Yes, I like the _finds the roots in complex conjugate pairs using only real arithmetic_ part of it.  When you get it working, consider [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  BTW, root finding is the source of my [pic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux-reinstate-monica?tab=profile).

Comment: There some way i can talk with you? I projecting something i think you can really help me now you cited your picture is related to root finding.

Comment: @Marino Let us start here.  Try forming your issue/goal in something that fits in a comment.  Perhaps set up a chat later.

Comment: So, i'm trying to built a program to generate a fractal given a function and using each point in a given range in the complex plane as initial guess of the root, basically built a program to generate a newton fractal.